# How to use accordion-group with template-url attribute

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I try to use the accordion directive with my own template. I use the following:

```
<accordion close-others="1">
  <accordion-group heading="First" is-open="1" template-url="template/accordion/accordion-mytemplate.html">
    First
  </accordion-group>
  <accordion-group heading="Second" template-url="template/accordion/accordion-mytemplate.html">
    Second
  </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

with template defined inside JavaScript file:

```
angular.module("template/accordion/accordion-mytemplate.html", []).run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put("template/accordion/accordion-mytemplate.html",
      "<div class=\"panel panel-default\">\n" +
      "<div class=\"panel-heading\">\n" +
      "<h1 class=\"panel-title\">\n" +
      "TEST: <a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" tabindex=\"0\" class=\"accordion-toggle\" ng-click=\"toggleOpen()\" accordion-transclude=\"heading\"><span ng-class=\"{'text-muted': isDisabled}\">{{heading}}</span></a>\n" +
      "</h1>\n" +
      "</div>\n" +
      "<div class=\"panel-collapse collapse\" collapse=\"!isOpen\">\n" +
      " <div class=\"panel-body\" ng-transclude></div>\n" +
      "</div>\n" +
      "</div>\n" +
      "");
}]);
```

and unfortunately it doesn't work for both work when I use $templateCache or I have template saved directly in *template/accordion/accordion-mytemplate.html* file (this way is preffered by me).

Can anybody describe me how to use ui.bootstrap.accordion with customized  template and why template-url attribute doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try upgrading to the latest version of `angular-bootstrap`. Older versions did not support the `template-url` attribute.